# Alphabet Paging Highlight active alphabet

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

```html
 
   

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAlphabet" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Value")%>' OnClick="Alphabet_Click"                                              CssClass="listbtn" Width="31px" Height="15px" />
<div class="clear-list">
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkAlphabet" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

********

This is my Code Behind :

***********

 protected void Alphabet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    LinkButton lnkAlphabetID = (LinkButton)sender;
    lnkAlphabetID.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    ViewState["CurrentAlphabet"] = lnkAlphabetID.Text;
    this.GenerateAlphabets();
    this.BindDataList("");
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "getdata", "javascript:Highlight()", true);

        }
```

How to SHow Selected Alphabet Click Active on click. (Alphabets are A to Z ) ? Change Background Color on Click of Alphabets

Comment: Why you are doing this `this.GenerateAlphabets();
    this.BindDataList("");` in `Alphabet_click`?

Comment: Generate Alphabets is to generate alphabets from A to Z 
like this,
 for (int i = 66; i <= 90; i++)
            {
                alphabet = new Alphabet();
                alphabet.Value = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(i);
                alphabet.isNotSelected = !alphabet.Value
                        .Equals(ViewState["CurrentAlphabet"]);
                alphabets.Add(alphabet);
            }
Binddatalist is i am using Datalist inside repeater

Comment: Ok, since on each click , you are generating and binding the list, some of property that are set ( like `BakcColor` = Red) before binding, are lost,and hence are not shown on clicking alphabet.

Comment: i am trying to change background color and showing it as active when any alphabets (A to Z) is clicked.

Comment: Can you comment all lines after this `ViewState["CurrentAlphabet"] = lnkAlphabetID.Text;` and try.

Comment: LinkButton Doesnot work.

Comment: I had a Radio Buttons, On Check of Radio Button i display DataList Result and on linkbutton (A to Z) i fillter the datalist result alphabetically,